# SQL - Catch Error in Transaction() Function in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have the following code:

```
await sails.getDatastore().transaction(async function(db, proceed) {
  for(var ctr1 = 0; ctr1 < tables.length; ctr1++) {
    for(var ctr2 = 0; ctr2 < tblData[0].length; ctr2++) {
      var colData = tblData[0][ctr2];

      if(tables[ctr1] == 'AD5300') await Items.create(colData).usingConnection(db);
      if(ctr1 == tables.length - 1 && ctr2 == tblData[0].length - 1) return proceed();
    }
  }
});
return exits.success({ "STATUS" : "1" });
```

It works and there is nothing else to worry here (for now at least).
The only issue I'm having here is that, if an error occurs on the line

```
if(tables[ctr1] == 'AD5300') await Items.create(colData).usingConnection(db);
```

It ends the process. What I want is to get the error message so I could parse the details with my own modified response. Is there a way to do that?

If I'm not mistaken, this is the latest version of Sails. Sails 1.0 I believe, but I could be wrong.

I'm using this link as reference:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/transaction

Comment: So you need make error from SQL and pass it to your sailsjs code, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a .intercept() method at the end of your query. As arguments, you pass in the error type you would like to catch and then a function for how you want to handle them.
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/intercept

EDIT:
After looking again, my answer above won't solve your problem, but I would like to leave it because the use of intercept will still be helpful to some.

You can now remove the `proceed` from your transaction and add a catch below. This will allow you to catch the error without halting the process.